# How can I combine or extend properties in a JSON Schema?

Tags: javascript, jsonschema, ajv

If I have an array of items and the items share some properties and have different ones as well.

1. Is there a way to extend/patch the common properties with different ones?
2. Can I use `$switch` inside object properties? I know it's used outside at the root level, but is there a way to perform conditions inside the properties?

I have trying to find any solution for such issue but can't seem to reach anything so far.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding what you can use inside the `properties` keyword:

> The value of "properties" MUST be an object.  Each value of this
> object MUST be a valid JSON Schema.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-00#section-6.5.4

`$switch` however, is not part of the JSON Schema specification, so while it may work when using ajv, it probably won't work for anyone else.

In addition, there's no way to "extend/patch" common properties with different ones. You can KIND OF extend properties if you use `allOf` with one object using a `$ref` and another your extension schema.

Comment: Your KIND OF solution is close to what I have reached so far. After defining the `properties`, I used `anyOf` to ref the extra properties I need to add. When compiling, all `properties` including the referenced ones appear as if they have been added together form the beginning.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but OK. Make sure you have some tests to confirm the schema works as you expect. Once you've reached your final solution, feel free to post it as an answer for others to find. Answering your own question is a valid option. (It's also useful to upvote answers you find helpful=] )

Answer (score 0):

What I finally managed to do is as follows:

```
items: {
    type: 'object',
    oneOf: [
        { $ref: '#/definitions/button' },
        { $ref: '#/definitions/select' },
    ],

    properties: {
        name: {
            $ref:`${DEFINITIONS_SCHEMA}#/definitions/non_empty_string`,
           // Normal object properties
        },
    }
}
```

The `properties` contain the normal object properties. The definitions in either `button` or `select` begins with properties as follow:

```
button: {
    properties:{
    }
}
```

When the schema is complied, the would be now two `properties` object inside of items. AJV merges them into a single `properties` object, appearing as if all were written together from the beginning.

I have written tests to confirm the previous.